# C# Monotouch/Xamarin.iOS - Custom MPMediaPickerController

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, mpmediapickercontroller

I need to implement functionality into an `iOS` app to allow the user to see a list of all the songs from their iphone's hard drive.

So far I've done this using the `MPMediaPickerController`.

The problem is of course, that the default look and feel of the `MPMediaPickerController` does not fit in with the rest of my application.

Is it possible to completely customize the `MPMediaPickerController`'s appearance?

Alternatively, is it possible to pull the list of songs from my iPhones hard drive into a custom listview design, instead of using the `MPMediaPickerController`?

**Update**

1. Some further research has brought up the following, which may be the answer - [iPod Access](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/UsingTheiPodLibrary/UsingTheiPodLibrary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH101-SW1)

Comment: Did you end up figuring out how to do this?

Comment: Yes, you have to query the phone yourself and then just roll your own list. I'll post a full answer once I can get hold of my source control.